# How to bind tinymce to the closest textarea when click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, closest

I have multiple textareas where tinymce is binded on.
To prevent loading tinymce to all the textareas, i use an onclick event.
Hit the button class `open-modal` opens a modal in which a textarea.
What i want to achieve: Bind tinymce to the closest textarea only from the modal.

This is what i have so far:

```
$(".open-modal").click( function() {    
    tinyMCE.init({      
        selector: "textarea",
```

So what i am looking for is something like this:

```
$(".open-modal").click( function() {    
    tinyMCE.init({      
        $(this).closest(selector): "textarea", // no proper code but i hope the intention is clear
```

Comment: Use the TinyMCE jquery plugin and instantiate it on the element directly: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/jquery/

Comment: @Rory It took me some time to figure out this but this was the correct solution to my issue.`$(this).siblings('.modal').find('textarea').tinymce({ // search class .modal and bind to textarea` works great now!